# Returning a specific value from a pandas dataframe after searching an entire column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following portion of my code below.

```
self.result_rows=summer17.index[summer17['Company'].str.contains(self.searche1_value.get(),na=False,case=False)]
self.c0=0
print(summer17.iloc[self.result_rows,self.c0])
```

and the output is

```
0    CAPS
Name: Company, dtype: object
```

What I am trying to do is to pass the value (in this case CAPS) from that specific cell into the variable results_rows. THe problem is what I'm getting in return is a bunch of data about the dataframe that I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the row_indexer parameter as a an array so `iloc` method returns a series( which contains data about the dataframe). If you want the values you use values accessor i.e `print(summer17.iloc[self.result_rows,self.c0].values)`

Example Dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3,5,6],[1,3,5,7,9,11]])
df.iloc[[0],0]
```

Output:

```
0    0
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

So with values accessor i.e `df.iloc[[0],0].values` Output:

```
array([0])
```

Comment: So I just ran this and it returns ['CAPS'] not just CAPS. I know this is a step in the right direction but I can't seem to find any documentation on .values and methods that can be used with it.